Gibbs phase rule argument about battery voltage dependency on the state of charge
I'm studying battery physics, particularly the dynamics of full discharge, and I am having trouble understanding an argument that is based on the Gibbs phase rule
$$F=C-P+2.$$
I understand the phase rule ($C$ is the number of components (atoms or molecule species), $P$ is the number of phases, and $F$ is the number of degrees of freedom, which is equal to the number of intensive thermodynamic parameters needed to fully define the system and all of its properties).
The text I'm reading (Advanced Batteries by Robert Huggins) then considers a lithium iodine battery cell. The lithium electrode is just a solid with one elemental species, so for the lithium electrode, $F=2$; a definite temperature and pressure is all that is needed to specify the state of all intensive variables, and electric potential is an intensive variable, so the potential at the electrode cannot depend on the state of charge. Huggins then makes the same argument for the iodine electrode, and if neither electrode potential is dependent on the state of charge, then the terminal voltage of the cell won't be either.
But no reference is made to the lithium iodide that is forming during the reaction powering the cell! Why can we ignore the reaction front and phase of the LiI forming during the cell reaction in this argument? Any help understanding Gibbs's phase arguments about the state of charge in a battery is welcome.

I think I may have answered my own question: The LiI front between the two electrodes is also just a single phase and component, so unless there is diffusion of unreacted Li or I into any one of the three phase sections then every section has $F=2$, so there is no dependence of the potential in any region on the state of charge.
